# ERROR: The conversion of string " Declare @RepInt=" to double is not valid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have this query

```
 Dim count as integer = 4

 Dim sql As String = " DECLARE @rep INT = " + count + "; " + _
                            " WITH cte AS " + _
                        " ( " + _
                            " SELECT TOP (@rep) " + _
                                " ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS N " + _
                            " FROM sys.All_Columns ac1 " + _
                            " CROSS JOIN sys.ALL_Columns ac2 " + _
                        " ) " + _
                        " SELECT t.Barcode" + _
                        " FROM A_Documents t " + _
                        " CROSS JOIN cte " + _
                        " where idDocument = 'doc-123456' " + _
                        " ORDER BY t.Barcode desc; "
```

If I put a number without a var, ist works:

```
Dim sql As String = " DECLARE @rep INT = 4; " + _
```

But when I put my COUNT var, is not work:

```
 Dim sql As String = " DECLARE @rep INT = " + count + "; " + _
```

And appears this error message:

> The conversion  of string " Declare @RepInt=" to double is not valid

Comment: Actually you don't need to declare variable. You can pass it immediately inside `TOP( + count + )`. Second think about using parameter binding not string concatenation. Also if you need to concatenate convert  `count` to string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help again, I can´t tick your comment because is not an answer

Comment: Never mind, upvote answers below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's the expected behaviour of the `+` operator.

when you feed a number variable to it then the system attempts to convert all the other objects to that numeric type to complete the addition, hence the exception.

imho this is a feature because allows you to exactly know what you are concatenating.

the solution:

```
Dim sql As String = " DECLARE @rep INT = " + count.ToString + "; " + _
```

Answer (score 2):

When you try to add a string and a number, it will try to convert the string to a number. You can use the `&` operator instead, which will convert anything that isn't a string to a string:

```
Dim sql As String = " DECLARE @rep INT = " & count & "; " + _
```